# dropdownlistfor to a string to use in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

in my script code, i would like to get the html content of the droplistfor and put it to a variable, but when i try it, it gives me an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
var select_doc_types = @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DocumentTypes, Model.DocumentTypes, Resources.Select, new { @class = "form-control" });
```

Why is it according to you ?

is there a way to do it without calling a partial view to get the string values.

Thanks

Comment: what are you going to use select_doc_types for?

Comment: Hi vivek, i concanate it with another html string, and append it to a div in the js codes

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
var select_doc_types = = (Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DocumentTypes, Model.DocumentTypes, Resources.Select, new { @class = "form-control" })).ToString();
```

Basically DropDownListFor returns MvcHtmlString you need to convert to string. Hope it helps

Comment: Hi vivek, still the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I end up doing that, it works just fine:

```
var select_doc_types = "<select class='form-control'><option selected='selected' disable>Please Choose...</option>"+
                    foreach (var item in Model.DocumentTypes)
                    {
                        <text>"<option> @item.Text </option>" + </text>
                    }
                    "</select>";
```

Comment: I see. What is the value does Resources.Select has?